# Property 'provideStore' does not exist on type 'typeof StoreModule'

Tags: angular, ngrx

I reckon they published some breaking changes, this is the error message that I get:

> Property 'provideStore' does not exist on type 'typeof StoreModule'.

I googled this error-message, but did not find anything. Nevertheless I guess there have been API-Updates that I am not aware of.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Solved it:**

https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/349

yes, it was deprecated, use "forRoot" instead

The method "provideStore" has been renamed to "forRoot", so that one better understands what this method does.