# NullInjectorError: No provider for Store

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm receiving the following error when running my unit tests:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[BlogService -> Store]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BlogService -> Store]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!
```

Here is the code in my test file:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { BlogService } from './blog.service';

describe('BlogService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [BlogService]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([BlogService], (service: BlogService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

I'm not  sure why this error is occuring. I thought the 'inject' call instantiates the service.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if your service is referencing an ngrx store then you need to import the ngrx modules.  I am making an assumption right now that you are doing that in your AppModule.  You need to duplicate that in your TestBed module.  I generally create a test ngrx module that does all that and then I can just import that in any spec file that references Store

Comment: I think `providers: [providers: [provideMockStore({})],]` in addition is also useful.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the ngrx mock store:

```
import { provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [provideMockStore({})],
    });
  });
```

You can define a specific state and pass it as method parameter.

Answer (score 14):

As stated [here](https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/78)

```
Add following to the specs.ts file:
// Add the import the module from the package 
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

   // Add the imported module to the imports array in beforeEach 
   beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        StoreModule.provideStore({})
      ],
      declarations: [
        // The component that's being tested
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

And if you get error `Property 'provideStore' does not exist on type 'typeof StoreModule` use forRoot `instead` of `provideStore`.
Also look [here](https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/349) and here is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412148/property-providestore-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-storemodule).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(provideMockStore),
```